# cual seria la manera correcta de resolver este ejercicio en php?, yo lo estoy haciendo así pero la sintaxis esta mal

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<h2>Total carácteres</h2>
<form action="" method="post"></form>
<label>Ingrese carácter: 
    <textarea name="caracteres" id="" cols="10" rows="10">
    </textarea>
</label>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
<hr>

<?php
   $caracter = $_POST['caracteres'];

   while ($caracter != "@"){
        switch ($caracter) {
            case ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"):
                $tv += 1;   // total vocales
                break;
            case  "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
                  "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "Ñ", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z":
                $tc += 1;   // total consonantes
                break;
            case ($caracter >=0 && $caracter <= 9):
                $tn += 1;   // total números
            default:
               $totr += 1;  // total otros caracteres
                break;
        }
   }

   echo "<br>Total de Vocales: {$tv}";
   echo "<br>Total de Consonantes: {$tc}";
   echo "<br>Total de Números: {$tn}";
   echo "<br>Total Otros: {$totr}";
?>
```

`TDy.png

Comment: Tenes que explicar cual es el resultado esperado, cual es el resultado que recibis, y con que cosas estas probando...

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis que estas utilizando en los `case:` no es válida.

En cualquier caso tampoco creo que un switch sea la mejor forma de resolver este problema.

Un ejemplo de como lo puedes resolver puede ser el siguiente, he comentado el código para que puedas entenderlo facilmente:

```
<?php
function contar_caracteres(string $cadena) {
    // obtenemos la longitud
    $len = mb_strlen($cadena, 'UTF-8');
    // declaramos nuestros arreglos vacios
    $apariciones = array();
    $vocal = array();
    $consonante = array();
    $otros = array();
    // hacemos un bucle para comparar caracter a caracter
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        // extraemos los caracteres uno a uno
        $caracter = mb_substr($cadena, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
        // comprobamos si ya ha salido antes
        if(!array_key_exists($caracter, $apariciones)) {
            // si no ha aparecido antes lo añadimos al array apariciones
            $apariciones[$caracter] = 0;
        }
        // le sumamos 1 
        $apariciones[$caracter]++;

        // comprobamos si es una vocal
        if (preg_match('/[aeiouáéíóúü]/i', $caracter)) {
            // si lo es lo añadimos al array de vocales
            $vocal[$caracter] = $apariciones[$caracter];
        // comprobamos si es una consonante, ya que sabemos que no es una vocal podemos usar A-z
        } elseif (preg_match('/[A-z]/i', $caracter)) {
            // si es una consonante la añadimos al array de consonantes
            $consonante[$caracter] = $apariciones[$caracter];
        } else {
            // si no es ni vocal ni consonante la añadimos al array otros
            $otros[$caracter] = $apariciones[$caracter];
        }
    }
    // Retornamos un array con todo
    return array('apariciones' => $apariciones, 'vocal' => $vocal, 'consonantes' => $consonante, 'otros' => $otros);
}

// definimos la cadena
$frase = 'Esto es una cadena @ con una arroba en medio';

// hacemos explode por la arroba para obtener la primera parte
$explode_arroba = explode('@', $frase);
// contamos los caracteres
$general = contar_caracteres($explode_arroba[0]);

echo 'Total vocales: '.array_sum($general['vocales'])."\n";
echo 'Total consonantes: '.array_sum($general['consonantes'])."\n";
echo 'Total otros: '.array_sum($general['otros'])."\n";
echo 'Total caracteres: '.array_sum($general['apariciones'])."\n";

print_r($general);
```

Resultado:

```
Total vocales: 8
Total consonantes: 7
Total otros: 4
Total caracteres: 19

Array
(
    [apariciones] => Array
        (
            [E] => 1
            [s] => 2
            [t] => 1
            [o] => 1
            [ ] => 4
            [e] => 2
            [u] => 1
            [n] => 2
            [a] => 3
            [c] => 1
            [d] => 1
        )

    [vocales] => Array
        (
            [E] => 1
            [o] => 1
            [e] => 2
            [u] => 1
            [a] => 3
        )

    [consonantes] => Array
        (
            [s] => 2
            [t] => 1
            [n] => 2
            [c] => 1
            [d] => 1
        )

    [otros] => Array
        (
            [ ] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: wauuu q interesante código, pero dime amigo, puedo usar el While en vez del Explode ??

Comment: El explode es para cortar la cadena por la `@` y analizar solo el testo hasta ella, no entiendo que me indicas del `while`, explicate mejor.

Comment: me refiero a que se pueda escribir mientras la letra sea distinta a @, osea :  while ($frase != @)

Comment: Realmente no te entiendo, el `while` no tiene sentido a priori, bien podrías evitar el explode y añadir un condicional de corte en el `for` para que finalice la función si encuentra un determinado carácter,  sea la `@` u otro.

Comment: ok ok entonces el While queda descartado, solo quería saber si podría usarlo!

Comment: muchas gracias Xerif, claro q tu ayuda me sirvió de mucho xq ahora entendí mejor las expresiones regulares y el uso de las funciones, Dios te bendiga mi amigo!